# Translate page using selenium + chrome

Tags: google-chrome, selenium

Is there a way to initiate translating current page in google chrome using selenium?
This is different from changing preference which translates all pages nor setting -lang as command line argument which changes google chrome's language.
I want to translate page on-demand based on the url.

I am using chromedriver + selenium web driver for c#
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-translate/aapbdbdomjkkjkaonfhkkikfgjllcleb?hl=en](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-translate/aapbdbdomjkkjkaonfhkkikfgjllcleb?hl=en%20google%20chrome) google chrome extension to fulfill your requirement. You can automate this utility using autoit.

To add an extension for chrome driver please refer to this link:

[HOW TO CREATE .CRX FILE FROM ALREADY INSTALLED CHROME EXTENSION?](http://www.helloselenium.com/2014/09/how-to-create-crx-file-from-already.html)

[HOW TO ADD AN EXTENSION TO GOOGLE CHROME INSTANCE OF SELENIUM WEBDRIVER?](http://www.helloselenium.com/2014/09/how-to-add-extension-to-google-chrome.html)

Comment: The first lik is not working and can you please share some coded sample